# How to make the column color grade depends on the column length (eg. from light green to dark green or (green levels))

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I wanted to make the column or bar color different depending on its values in ggplot2 Column Bar (eg. from light green to dark green or (green levels)).

I have a simple example that needed two modifications.

**1) change the positive column to green and negative to red**

**2) make the color continuous from light to dark depending on the bar length**

I tried to solve the first one but got an error. If you can help me to solve both, I will really appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

```
data.test <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5],    
                   y = c(-4, 2, 7, 3, -5),
                  z = c("Negative","Positive","Positive","Positive","Negative"))

  ggplot(data.test, aes(x, y)) +               
  geom_col(position = "identity",aes(fill = z)) #+
    #scale_fill_manual(values = ifelse(data.test$y[1] > 0, c("#359206", "#de0025")
                                  #    ,c("#de0025","#359206")))
```

#the last two lines in the code is a trial to make positive green and negative red but it comes with an error as following :

```
Error in `f()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Even though I provided 2 in my `scale_fill_manual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "sign" of your data is already reflected in column `y`, you can use it to fill your plot. What you need is `scale_fill_gradient`, which allows gradient colouring of your plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data.test <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5],    
                        y = c(-4, 2, 7, 3, -5),
                        z = c("Negative","Positive","Positive","Positive","Negative"))

ggplot(data.test, aes(x, y, fill = y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>